# Select data from mysql with php, display in html dropdown list and insert selected value as URL parameter via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

First, please understand I have just begun to learn php, javascript and ajax in the past 10 days so I will need some hand-holding and step-by-step examples and guidance. I've carefully read the courses for those topics at w3schools and found them very helpful; as a result, I was able to write some basic code for my project by using their examples and other snippets I've found here and other sites.

This post is a little lengthy so I can explain my ultimate goal for this code and what I've already tried.

I have started writing a piece of very complex code that has multiple parts, but the final result will be a dropdown selection list with an image thumbnail button of the main_image of that page linked to an external URL which is dynamically created based on the user's dropdown list selection.

This is my project:

I am building a website with Joomla 3.x.x, Bootstrap 3 and j2store (with other components and modules) that features photos for sale as digital images and that can be applied to physical products (canvas prints, t-shirts, coffee mugs, etc). Those physical products exist on a 3rd party website (Zazzle) which are embedded into my private website with Zazzle's RSS feed and another 3rd party javascript code (to embed Zazzle RSS feed grid displays into my website).

The Zazzle API allows my users to choose any image from my private website and apply that image to any product available in Zazzle's marketplace.

My users would ultimately select a category of products from a dropdown list on my website and then click a button that would open a new window to connect to the Zazzle marketplace which would display a grid of relevant physical products featuring the image shown on the active page of my website where the user clicked the button.

For example, the user starts by looking at the page on my website with the main_image "Light Purple African Daisy", chooses a category of electronic products from a dropdown list and then clicks the "Design Your Own Gifts" button which opens a new window, connects to the Zazzle marketplace and displays a grid of electronic products showing the "Light Purple African Daisy" image on the user's chosen products.

The URL behind the "Design Your Own Gifts" button needs to be created dynamically with the selected value after the user chooses a category of products from a dropdown list on my website.

This is the Zazzle API I need to use:

```
https://www.zazzle.com/api/create/at-238500395169782226?rf=238500395169782226&ax=DesignBlast&sr=250508120301240636&cg= <DYNAMIC CATEGORY ID FROM DROPDOWN SELECTION LIST> &t__useQpc=false&ed=true&t__smart=false&continueUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zazzle.com%2Fcapturedimagesmaine&tc=&ic=&t_coverimage_iid= <URLENCODED DYNAMIC PATH OF ACTIVE PAGE MAIN_IMAGE>"
```

I have created 2 tables in mysql database that hold the Names, Category IDs and Department IDs for the products in my Zazzle marketplace. I am also getting the main_image path from my j2store productimages table.

The code I have been able to write so far accomplishes the following tasks:

1. Connect to the database
2. Choose Columns/Tables
3. GET Data from Columns/Tables
4. Create HTML Form to Display Result of MYSQL Query
5. Create Dropdown Selection List of Query Results
6. Echo encoded URL with Zazzle API concatenated with Parameters/Dynamic Values

This is my code so far:

```
 <div class="form-group" style="margin: 30px 10%;">
<h3>Create Zazzle Products</h3><p><h4>Select a Template Category</h4>
<form name="create-zproducts" id="create-zproducts" action="create-zproduct.php" method="POST">
    <?php
                //connection
                $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');
                if (!$con) {
                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
                $sql="SELECT * FROM david_cim_template_categories, david_j2store_productimages";
                $cg = $_GET['cim_template_cg'];
                $coverimage_iid = $_GET['main_image'];
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    ?>
    <select name="selectZcategories" id="selectZcategories">
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['cim_template_cg'].':'.$row['cim_template_cgname']'">'.$row['cim_template_cgname'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <button onclick="ajaxFunction();">Submit</button><br /><br />

<?php

    <script>

    function ajaxFunction() {
        var selectedData=$("#selectZcategories option:selected").val();

   $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url: "select_zproduct.php",
      data: { selection : selectedData },
      success: function (html) {
          //Success handling
      }
   })
}   
    </script>

?>

<?php
    echo $ZAPI = "https://www.zazzle.com/api/create/at-238500395169782226?rf=238500395169782226&ax=DesignBlast&sr=250508120301240636&cg=";
    echo $cg = ['cim_template_cg'];
    echo $ZPARAM = "&t__useQpc=false&ed=true&t__smart=false&continueUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zazzle.com%2Fcapturedimagesmaine&tc=&ic=&t_coverimage_iid=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.capturedimagesofmaine.com%2Fimages%2Fproducts%2Foriginal%2F";
    echo $coverimage_iid = ['main_image'];
    echo $product_text = "&t_text1_txt=Welcome";
?>
</form>
</div>

// new file (select_zproduct.php) added to same path as create_zproduct.php
// contents of select_zproduct.php below:
<?php
if( isset($_POST['selection']) )
{
   $selecterData=$_POST['selection'];
   $selecterArrayData=explode(':', $selecterData);

   $cg=$selecterArrayData[0];
   $coverimage_iid=$selecterArrayData[1];

   $url='https://www.zazzle.com/api/create/at-238500395169782226?rf=238500395169782226&ax=DesignBlast&sr=250508120301240636&cg='.$cg.'&t__useQpc=false&ed=true&t__smart=false&continueUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zazzle.com%2Fcapturedimagesmaine&tc=&ic=&t_coverimage_iid='.$coverimage_iid.'';
   ?>
   <script>
      window.location.href=<?php echo $url; ?>;
   </script>
   <?php
}
?>
```

The code above is just the beginning of what I've been able to write by myself so far.

My obstacle at the moment is not being able to make the " cg= " parameter display the numeric value of $cg= which was selected by the user from the dropdown list. The current code returns the word "Array" in the URL instead of the selected value. (eg. cg=Array instead of cg=196215449301144739)

I believe I need to use AJAX and Javascript to accomplish this action but I don't know enough to write it by myself yet.

The Code I Need to Write will accomplish the following tasks:

7. Assign proper $variables to URL fragments ($ZAPI, $cg, etc) to be used for concatenation
8. Assign proper $variables to database dropdown SELECTION Result to be used in the URL above
9. Concatenate all $variables
10. Parse all $variables
11. Embed final encoded URL into button
12. Use thumbnail of active page main_image as button image src

What I need to know right now is how do I insert the numeric value of 'cim_template_cg' into the " cg= " parameter in the final URL so the final URL will output " &cg=196215449301144739 " when the user selects the 'cim_template_cgname' associated with that cg=.

Once I see the solution I can apply it to the other dynamic values I need to create. I've only written one javascript code with help from a snippet so any AJAX or Javascript code that needs to be written will need to be shown to me in an example and describing related files, please.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood your question properly, you have the necessary data to achieve this, i.e. you have the URL path and ID from the database, as well as the URL string, which needs these database values dynamically added upon selection?

And to answer one of your questions, yes this can be done via AJAX if you wish for the PHP logic to be handled in a seperate file.

What you could do, is concatenate your URL path and ID from the database with a seperator value that you could perform an `explode();` on to get the values.

so, your `<select>` would look something like this instead:

```
<select name="selectZcategories" id="zCategories">
  <?php
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['cim_template_cg'].':'.$row['cim_template_cgname'].'">'.$row['cim_template_cgname'].'</option>';
  }
  ?>
</select>
```

Now to the AJAX function. Personally, I use the jQuery library, simply because it makes things easy and simple. It simplifies a lot of the code, so I am going to go by the jQuery standards in my AJAX example. If you wish to use jQuery AJAX to achieve the same results, you will need to install jQuery into a library that you include like any other normal JS/CSS file etc.

```
function ajaxFunction() {
   var selectedData=$("#zCategories option:selected").val();

   $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url: "/path/to/file.php",
      data: { selection : selectedData },
      success: function (html) {
          //Success handling
      }
   })
}
```

What this achieves, is that the function will take the selected value of the `<select>` and parse the data to another file using the POST method. You are able to do a lot of things in the success function if you so desire, but for our purpose, I'll simply perform the redirect in the PHP file.

When the data has been parsed to the other file, you then perform an `explode();` on the value to split it up into our two variables that we will parse along in our URL.

The PHP file could look something like this:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['selection']) )
{
   $selecterData=$_POST['selection'];
   $selecterArrayData=explode(':', $selecterData);

   $categoryID=$selecterArrayData[0];
   $imagePath=$selecterArrayData[1];

   $url='https://www.zazzle.com/api/create/at-238500395169782226?rf=238500395169782226&ax=DesignBlast&sr=250508120301240636&cg='.$categoryID.'&t__useQpc=false&ed=true&t__smart=false&continueUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zazzle.com%2Fcapturedimagesmaine&tc=&ic=&t_coverimage_iid='.$imagePath.'';
   ?>
   <script>
      window.location.href=<?php echo $url; ?>;
   </script>
   <?php
}
?>
```

How you call the AJAX function initially is up to you. It could be via a button for instance.

```
<button onclick="ajaxFunction();">Submit</button>
```

Hope this helped, or pointed you towards the right direction.

For tests as per request by your comment,

Ajax for test:

```
function ajaxFunction() {
   var selectedData=$("#zCategories option:selected").val();

   $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url: "/path/to/file.php",
      data: { selection : selectedData },
      success: function (html) {
          //Success handling
          alert(html);
      }
   })
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    if( isset($_POST['selection']) )
    {
       $selecterData=$_POST['selection'];
       $selecterArrayData=explode(':', $selecterData);

       $categoryID=$selecterArrayData[0];
       $imagePath=$selecterArrayData[1];

       $url='https://www.zazzle.com/api/create/at-238500395169782226?rf=238500395169782226&ax=DesignBlast&sr=250508120301240636&cg='.$categoryID.'&t__useQpc=false&ed=true&t__smart=false&continueUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zazzle.com%2Fcapturedimagesmaine&tc=&ic=&t_coverimage_iid='.$imagePath.'';

       echo 'cg: '.$categoryID.' img path: '.$imagePath;
       ?>
       <script>
          //window.location.href=<?php echo $url; ?>;
       </script>
       <?php
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the developer of J2Store for help with getting the main_image value from the active J2Store product page and embedding my final API URL into my J2Store product pages so he rewrote my code to integrate error-free with both Joomla and J2Store, as follows:

```
<?php
/**
* @package J2Store
* @copyright Copyright (c)2014-17 Ramesh Elamathi / J2Store.org
* @license GNU GPL v3 or later
*
* Bootstrap 2 layout of product detail
*/
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)->select('*')->from('#__cim_template_categories');
$db->setQuery($query);
$cg_values = $db->loadObjectList();
$image_path = JUri::root();
$main_image = $image_path.$this->product->main_image;

//$zazzle_api = 'https://www.zazzle.com/api/create/at-238500395169782226';
$zazzle_api = 'https://www.zazzle.com/api/create/at-238500395169782226';
?>
<?php if(count($cg_values)): ?>
<div class="cg_values">
  <form method="get" class="zazzle_api_form" action="<?php echo $zazzle_api; ?>">
    <select name="cg" class="cg">
      <?php foreach($cg_values as $cg_value): ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $cg_value->cim_template_cg; ?>">
            <?php echo $cg_value->cim_template_cgname; ?>
          </option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="rf" value="238500395169782226" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ax" value="DesignBlast"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="sr" value="250508120301240636"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="t__useQpc" value="false"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="ed" value="true"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="t__smart" value="false"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="continueUrl" value="<?php echo urlencode('https://www.zazzle.com?www.capturedimagesmaine.com'); ?>"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="tc" value=""  />
    <input type="hidden" name="ic" value=""  />
    <input type="hidden" name="t_text1_txt" value=""  />
    <input type="hidden" name="t_coverimage_iid" value="<?php echo $main_image; ?>" 
/>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create Your Own Custom Gifts" 
/>
  </form>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```